# O que é encriptação end-to-end?

Tags: php, segurança, criptografia

Ouço muito falar desse negócio de criptografia *end-to-end* porém eu não consigo entender muito o que seja por que ela é chamada de "opção mais segura para a privacidade". Eu possuo dúvidas e as enumerei, vejam:

- O que é?
- Como funciona?
- Ela é inviolável?
- Existe maneira de se trabalhar ela no PHP?
- Suas vantagens e desvantagens

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normalmente o termo é usado fora do contexto de programação. Embora muitas vezes o que fazemos em uma aplicação, tipicamente web, tecnicamente seja parecido com a criptografia *end-to-end*, pela definição do termo é algo diferente. O termo é usado para indicar a segurança de tráfego de dados entre dois agentes particulares sem que tenha interferência de qualquer forma de terceiros.

Este *end-to-end* significa que a comunicação ocorre entre dois pontos finais. Isto é usado em e-mails e mensagens instantâneas, coisas que em geral não passam por um servidor ou se passam, apenas transitoriamente.

O termo não é usado quando um cliente se comunica com um servidor. Embora tecnicamente seja **possível usar o PHP** para fazer uma comunicação *end-to-end*, ele **não costuma ser usado** para isto.

Vamos dizer que você crie aplicativos que faça comunicação criptografada *end-to-end* passando pelo seu servidor PHP. Se a comunicação realmente é *end-to-end*, sua aplicação PHP nem precisa saber o conteúdo, ela lida apenas com dados genéricos. Ela não sabe se está criptografada ou não, não sabe o que tem ali. Se ela precisa e consegue saber, então você já não tem mais uma comunicação *end-to-end*.

E esse "consegue saber" pode ser direta ou indiretamente. Mesmo que a comunicação seja toda criptografada, se há alguma maneira de circundar isto, já estamos vendo uma falha e acho que o termo não poderia ser usado. Especialmente a troca de chaves para a criptografia pode se tornar problemática. E não vejo como resolver isto através de navegadores.

A **vantagem** dela é justamente não deixar intermediários interferiam no conteúdo. A **desvantagem** é que as duas pontas precisam garantir a comunicação segura por meios próprios e isto não é simples de fazer principalmente porque os usuários - em geral são leigos - precisam tomar providências que ele não entende e pode se equivocar.

Qualquer segurança é **inviolável** até que alguém viole. Como o termo é apenas um conceito e não uma tecnologia específica ele poderá ser mais ou menos inviolável de acordo com o que e como está sendo usado.

Vamos supor que você tenha uma aplicação JavaScript no seu celular e uma aplicação PHP no computador da sua casa. Ambos não estão comprometidos e possuem meios eficazes de criptografar os dados que eles trafegam entre si sem intermediários, eventualmente até por HTTPS. Acho que podemos dizer que o PHP foi usado para uma comunicação *end-to-end*. Tecnicamente acho que é E2E. Mas fazer isto não é típico, e nem é simples. E nem faz muito sentido, tem maneiras e tecnologias melhores para obter o mesmo ou melhor resultado.

Algumas tecnologias usadas para garantir comunicação segura *end-to-end*:

- [PGP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP)
- [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME)
- [OTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging)
- [Tresorit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tresorit)

Todas são formas específicas de usar criptografia "tradicional". Elas trabalham na **camada da aplicação**. O usuário é responsável por fazê-las funcionar. Elas usam um aplicativo de um fornecedor, uma utilitário de criptografia de outro, um transporte de outro, um servidor intermediário, quando há de outro, um certificado de outro e o serviço de por tudo isto junto de mais um outro e que preferencialmente deve ser o próprio usuário. Todos eles devem ser confiáveis. Idealmente eles devem ser auditados publicamente. Um serviço como o Telegram parece resolver grande partes das dificuldades mas tem um problema, eles fornecem tudo o que é necessário. Você tem que confiar neles. Não pode ter nenhum *back-door*. E muitas empresas colocam, até para não ter problemas legais.

Toda a criptografia é feita entre as partes finais e mesmo que os dados criptografados passem por intermediários, até que se prove o contrário, eles não podem ter acesso aos dados planos nem por um momento mínimo para não ferir o conceito.

Duvido que seja possível com a tecnologia atual que páginas web padrões consigam fazer todo o processo por conta própria sem intermediários pelo menos para a troca de chaves.

É possível fazer aplicações para comunicação E2E usando outros protocolos ou mesmo protocolos web mas de forma diferente dos navegadores.

Provavelmente ainda precisaria de um servidor para colocar as duas pontas em contato, o que já é uma quebra de privacidade porque alguém saberá quem está contactando quem. Já pensou nisto? Privacidade e inviolabilidade E2E total é muito difícil de se obter mesmo na vida real.

Se os aplicativos nas pontas fornecerem todos os meios para fazer o resto da comunicação, trocarem chaves que podem ser autenticadas (**precisa de certificado privado**) sem que elas possam ser usadas para decifrar os dados trafegados por quem não é a ponta, é E2E.

Fazer um *chat* e garantir coisas que você não pode ou não sabe efetivamente garantir pode trazer problemas legais dependendo da forma como isto for vendido ao usuário final. Como garantir inviolabilidade sendo um intermediário? É possível mas não é simples implementar, especialmente usando tecnologias frágeis como *scripts* PHP e navegadores. Certamente não será confiável se for feito armazenamento no servidor de mensagens e chaves em banco de dados ou outras formas.

Não sou um especialista no assunto mas em linhas gerais é isto.

Tentando juntar todas as partes do assunto:

- [Transmitir informações sem passar pelo servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49914/101)
- [O que é criptografia end-to-end? Como aplicá-la?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49809/101)
- [Dados recebidos de HTTPS vem encriptado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49842/101)
- [Como funciona a encriptação do Telegram](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49918/101)
- qual será a próxima? :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Interessante, pensei que era um algoritmo ou coisa do genero, Telegram por exemplo usa end-to-end para salvar seus dados, tenho algumas questoes, creio que possa me esclarecer, "Isto é usado em e-mails e mensagens instantâneas, coisas que em geral não passam por um servidor ou se passam, apesar transitoriamente." Como assim nao passam pelo servidor? Os dados nao tem que ser salvos em uma database por exemplo? me perdi aí..

Comment: Pois bem, eu desenvolvo um projeto e desdo principio eu achava a idéia de deixar os dados do banco de dados "cru" sem nenhum tipo de proteção um absurdo, desde então eu criptografo meus dados salvos e os descriptografo na hora de exibir ao usuario final, um exemplo disso foi um chat que desenvolvi, todos os dados do chat eram gravados na database e todos eram encriptados e na hora de listar eu os descriptografava.. A pergunta é, isso pode ser considerado criptografia end-to-end? Ou o fato dos dados passarem pelo meu servidor altera..?

Comment: Em mensagem instantâneas não costumam passar. No caso de e-mail passa mas se a criptografia foi feita entre os clientes apenas (normalmente por PGP), o servidor não participa do processo de criptografia, apesar de ele ser um agente intermediário do transporte ele não é agente da aplicação. Para o servidor são apenas dados indecifráveis. Só os clientes é que saberão o que fazer com estes dados. Que é diferente dos dados trafegados entre um navegador e um servidor PHP em condições normais. Aí o servidor participa, quem tem acesso ao servidor, pode interceptar o dado em determinado momento.

Comment: Este exemplo do *chat* não é *end-to-end*, seu servidor está participando e pode interferir no processo. Você, dono do *chat* não é num um *end* e nem o outro *end*. Só as pessoas conversando é que são. Você é intermediário e consegue saber o que se passa na conversa. E a´te mesmo outras pessoas poderiam se conseguirem acessar seu servidor. Criptografar os dados no DB não garante muita coisa. O transporte está criptografado? Está usando HTTPS, por exemplo? Quando chega ao servidor isto é descriptografado e até você criptografar para colocar no banco de dados, está desprotegido.

Comment: Realmente eu estou muito confuso no momento, pensei que estava fazendo de uma forma correta, Meu Deus será que perdi meu projeto? enfim... Mas os dados nao deveriam ser salvos? tipo, como eles exibem a conversa já trocada entao?

Comment: O que eu acho que pode ser considerado *end-to-end* se a criptografia acontecer no navegador e trafegue assim independente do protocolo e você pegue este dado já criptografado e que você não consegue fazer nada com este dado desta forma a não ser gravar e mandar para outro lugar, não consegue lê-lo ou alterá-lo. Aí só quem pode ser considerado o dono deste dado (de uma forma ou de outra) é que poderia receber e descriptografar o dado.

Comment: Agora me ficou mais claro, ou seja eu (servidor) apenas usar o dado para remeter a outra pessoa, isso ficou claro, mas como seria feita essa encriptaçao no navegador, HTTPS?

Comment: O que eu posso lhe dizer é que quase ninguém entende de segurança, mesmo desenvolvedores experientes. Conheço até alguns especialistas em segurança, que está longe de ser o meu caso, que cometem vários erros sobre o assunto. Se quer garantir segurança contrate um especialista. Segurança é um tema extremamente complicado. De maneira alguma dados de um *chat* precisam ser salvos. Isto é uma forma muito ingênua de fazer isto. A não ser que queira guardar histórico da conversa tem exatamente zero motivos para salvar os dados. Dependendo do caso o servidor nem precisa existir p/ a conversa em si.

Comment: Muito obrigado irei estudar e fazer pesquisas, Obrigado!!

Comment: Não pode ser HTTPS, tem que usar meios próprios, com chaves próprias que os usuários possuam e que para fazer certo elas devem possuir certificados pessoais, coisa que quase ninguém tem, e nem imaginam como fazer isto funcionar. É complicado para usuários leigos e só eles podem fazer isto nos seus computadores (claro que podem pedir para um técnico, mas você como servidor não pode ajudar em nada). Isto mais ou menos eu falei na resposta. o assunto é muito extenso para caber em uma pergunta. Para entender tudo teria que fazer perguntas bem específicas.

Comment: Entenda que *end-to-end* não pode ser influenciada por intermediários. Você como servidor neste exemplo que está usando não pode ajudar os usuários terem segurança/privacidade *end-to-end*. Só eles podem fazer algo. O máximo que pode fazer é colocar um *script* que facilite um pouco a vida deles e instruções do que fazer mas o resto tem que ser com eles. Se você se intrometer tecnicamente falando já não é *end-to-end*. E mesmo este *script* já pode comprometer, porque eles teriam que confiar nele, confiar que você não errou nele, de propósito ou sem querer.

Comment: "desde então eu criptografo meus dados salvos e os descriptografo na hora de exibir ao usuario final" E onde você guarda a chave? Já pensou que se um atacante tem acesso ao seu servidor, ele vai ver não só as mensagens cifradas mas a chave também? A única exceção é se essa chave estiver fora do BD, em um arquivo de configurações por exemplo - SQL Injection é um ataque bem comum, bem mais do que um acesso completo ao seu sistema de arquivos. Ou seja, ajuda um pouquinho sim, mas não é nem de longe tão mais seguro do que simplesmente guardar os dados crus mesmo. Às vezes o mais simples é melhor.

Comment: Andei pesquisando e nao obtive exito, existe alguma forma de enviar informaçoes do user 1 ao user 2 sem precisar de servidor (nao vejo como pois o servidor direciona os dados mas ok), para a assim conseguir o end-to-end...?

Comment: Isto já é outra pergunta mas para web padrão? Que eu saiba não. Web não é solução para todos os problemas.

Answer (score 6):

A [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49722/215) já explica o que é *end-to-end*, vou apenas complementar abordando suas dúvidas específicas:

> Ela é inviolável?

*Nada* é inviolável. Apenas a título de exemplo:

- Se uma computação está ocorrendo no servidor, o servidor pode se intrometer nela (não é *end-to-end*);
- Se o servidor somente te envia o código (JavaScript, por exemplo), e toda a criptografia/descriptografia ocorre no browser, *parece* que está tudo bem, mas pense: se você não confia no servidor, como saber se ele está mandando o JavaScript certo? Ele poderia substituir o seu script por outro, um que passe por cima da criptografia e mande os dados originais para algum outro lugar...
- Se você está usando um programa instalado no seu computador, e não uma página na web, eu pergunto: de onde você baixou esse programa? Você confia no seu fornecedor? Ele poderia ter um *backdoor* para acessar seus dados antes de criptografia...
- Você obteve o programa em formato fonte, verificou se estava tudo certo, e compilou você mesmo. Ok, mas [**seu compilador é confiável**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheKenThompsonHack)? Onde você o obteve, você confia no seu fornecedor? E o computador onde esse programa está executando, ele realmente faz o que você manda fazer, não tem nenhum *backdoor* no sistema operacional, ou mesmo no próprio *hadrware*?

  (Nota: esse último item é bastante extremo, mas ilustra o ponto que eu quero passar, que **você sempre tem que confiar em alguém**.)

> Existe maneira de se trabalhar ela no PHP?

Como já explicado, se o PHP processa os dados em formato plano, já não é mais *end-to-end*. E se ele serve o código que vai ser usado para o *end-to-end*, *em princípio* está tudo bem, mas no fim das contas ou o usuário confia no seu sistema, ou ele não vai executar um código servido por seu sistema...

> Suas vantagens e desvantagens

A principal vantagem é a redução das oportunidades de ataque, por reduzir o número de terceiros nos quais você precisa confiar. Como já dito, não é possível eliminar o requisito de confiança, mas reduzi-lo já é um avanço.

A maior desvantagem é que a responsabilidade pela segurança cai nos ombros do usuário final. Se este não for muito bem treinado, sua experiência com o sistema ficará gravemente prejudicada. A título de exemplo, digamos que seu servidor guarde em arquivo as comunicações passadas. Num determinado momento, o usuário esquece sua senha. Normalmente você poderia resetá-la, mas se essa senha e responsável por derivar a chave de criptografia, e você não a conhece (lembrando: do contrário não seria *end-to-end*), ao resetá-la o usuário perde o acesso a todo o seu arquivo...

Na mesma linha, se Alice quer se comunicar com Bob é necessário que ambos troquem chaves e/ou certificados de modo a estabelecer a comunicação *end-to-end*. Seu servidor pode ajudar nisso? De forma alguma! Se ele participasse da troca de chaves, ele estaria na posição perfeita para executar um ataque *Man-In-The-Middle*... Seus usuários precisam fazer essa troca e/ou verificação de identidade por um meio seguro, por exemplo pessoalmente. Se algum deles tomar um "atalho" (digamos, mandar a chave por e-mail) ele já compromete a segurança da comunicação (vai que o provedor de e-mail substitui a chave por uma de sua posse). Etc.

No geral, eu diria que os benefícios são poucos e os custos bastante altos. A menos que você tenha uma necessidade bem específica, e esteja disposto a usar os softwares mais adequados para tal (de preferência feitos por especialistas, e não *home-made*; o Maniero já cita alguns, eu acrescentaria o [GPG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) e o [Enigmail](https://www.enigmail.net/home/index.php) - para o envio de e-mails). Na minha empresa por exemplo, usamos um e-mail comum para tudo, só quando precisamos enviar algo bem confidencial (uma senha, por exemplo) é que fazemos uso dessas ferramentas. Usar por usar, não compensa, tem de haver um bom motivo por trás...

Comment: é complicado, como voce mesmo disse tudo precisa de um ponto de confiança. Estou tentando criar uma aplicação de chat end-to-end mas pelo visto nao poderei usar esse slogan..

Comment: Andei pesquisando e nao obtive exito, existe alguma forma de enviar informações do user 1 ao user 2 sem precisar de servidor (nao vejo como pois o servidor direciona os dados mas ok), para a assim conseguir o end-to-end...?

Comment: @user3715916 A questão não é usar ou não servidor, e sim garantir que somente os usuários 1 e 2 tenham acesso ao conteúdo no formato original. Se o conteúdo estiver encriptado, e o servidor não tiver a chave, então está tudo bem. O difícil é fazer com que user 1 e user 2 troquem de chaves sem que o servidor ganhe acesso a elas. P.S. Se ainda está interessado em comunicação sem servidor, estude *peer-to-peer*. [Aqui tem um exemplo de projeto](http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/) onde os usuários se comunicam diretamente uns com os outros, sem servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pelo link e informaçoes adicionais, eu estou estudando um pouco e cheguei nesse problema que voce mesmo mencionou " O difícil é fazer com que user 1 e user 2 troquem de chaves sem que o servidor ganhe acesso a elas" existe algum artigo ou algo do genero que explique como fazer a troca de chaves sem ninguem sabe-las?

Comment: Posso sugerir [esse artigo na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) (em inglês). Não espere encontrar uma solução 100%, já que esse é um problema em aberto... Mas a partir desse artigo você poderá estudar e avaliar as principais soluções existentes ([Infraestrutura de Chaves Públicas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infraestrutura_de_Chaves_P%C3%BAblicas) - [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) - e [*Web of Trust*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)), bem como suas limitações.

Answer (score 0):

> Um serviço como o Telegram parece resolver grande partes das dificuldades mas tem um problema, eles fornecem tudo o que é necessário. Você tem que confiar neles. Não pode ter nenhum back-door.

Só queria acrescentar que o Telegram é o melhor exemplo recente que eu vi de encriptação end-to-end, mas é isso: use os servers deles.
Porém, consultando o  código, dá para ter ideia de como é a estrutura que eles usam. 
Dá para conferir [aqui](https://telegram.org/apps#source-code), nos links do GitHub que eles colocam.

Aqui eles explicam superficialmente como usam a encriptação end-to-end no secret chat:

> When a secret chat is created, the participating devices exchange encryption keys using the so called Diffie-Hellman key exchange. After the secure end-to-end connection has been established, we generate a picture that visualizes the encryption key for your chat. You can then compare this image with the one your friend has — if the two images are the same, you can be sure that the secret chat is secure and no man-in-the-middle attack can possibly succeed. [(Link)](https://telegram.org/faq#q-whats-this-encryption-key-39-thing)