# O que é criptografia end-to-end? Como aplicá-la?

Tags: criptografia, aes

De acordo com tudo que pesquisei e com a ajuda do @Maniero eu cheguei a conclusão:

"Criptografia *end-to-end* é feita quando apenas os pontos da conexão tem acesso a chave que vai descriptografar o conteúdo, ou seja os dados podem ATÉ passar ou ficar no servidor, mas eles deverão estar lá de forma encriptada de tal forma que sejam dados ilegíveis e nulos para os demais".

Sinceramente eu acho isto incrível e estou muito entusiasmado para adaptar minha aplicação a este tipo de criptografia, no momento eu uso uma chave global interna para encriptar os dados de minha database usando o algoritmo **AES-128 ECB**.

Não poderei adaptar todo meu projeto para este tipo de criptografia por que senão boa parte dele seria esquartejado, "buscar por usuários" seria praticamente impossível de realizar... enfim não é o foco da questão, apenas me empolguei.

Eu possuo um chat onde no momento todos seus dados são gravados encriptadamente na *database* e eu gostaria de adaptá-lo ao *end-to-end*. Levando em consideração que para isso uma chave deverá ser criada para cada ponto (usuário a receber e a enviar), minhas três dúvidas são:

- Existe especificações para criar estas chaves?
- Como eu vou informar ao usuário na outra ponta a minha chave para ele decriptar minhas mensagens que enviarei?
- A minha maior dúvida é: Qual o meio de comunicação que posso usar entre os usuários *websockets*?

Comment: acredito que esteja a falar de RSA, porém tanto o AES e o RSA tem propósitos diferentes, e possuem os seus respectivos pontos positivos e negativos. de forma geral, RSA só é interessante quando se pretende compartilhar informação sigilosa com terceiros por um canal não seguro.
O ideal seria fazer a criptografia por AES (por ser mais rapida) e compatilhar a chave AES utilizando o RSA (Public-Key)

Comment: @TobyMosque interessante o que disse, poderia me informar mais? Uso PHP.

Comment: Não tenho knowhow em PHP, mas posso lhe dizer que uma conexão HTTPS utiliza SSL, e SSL utiliza RSA, então você poderia enviar as suas chaves atraves de um link seguro (HTTPS) e o arquivo criptografado por um link não seguro (HTTP), mas neste caso é interresante você utilizar uma Key/IV diferente a cada transmissão.

Answer (score 2):

A respeito da sua pergunta:

> Como eu vou informar ao usuário na outra ponta a minha chave para ele
>   decriptar minhas mensagens que enviarei?

Minha sugestão número 1 seria você ter, no momento da criação do usuário, a criação das chaves pública e privada.
Deixe seu servidor cuidar da distribuição da chave pública. Por exemplo:
Usuário A vai conversar com usuário B. Então o seu servidor vai deixar deixar a chave pública de A na sessão de B e a chave pública de B na sessão de A. 
Assim, B poderia decriptar o que vier de A e vice versa.

Minha sugestão 2, seria bem mais fácil, levando em consideração que você já tem um servidor cuidando de tudo... seria ter só o servidor ter uma chave privada e cada usuário teria a chave pública do servidor. Assim, o usuário mandaria a mensagem encriptada para o servidor usando a chave pública do servidor e o servidor decriptaria isso usando a chave privada dele. A idéia é que só usuários seriam capazes de entender o que o servidor "diz". Se alguem tentar um "man-in-the-middle", ele não teria acesso a mensagem.

E completando de forma mais específica, use um web server para fazer o meio de campo. Creio que 100% deles são capazes de tratar de coisas relacionadas a criptografia. Alguns são mais simples de configurar e outros mais complexos. Você vai apenas brincar com cripto (acadêmico) ou é algo pro trabalho? Isso são algumas coisas pra levar em consideração.

Comment: É acadêmico e futuramente a trabalho, veja que nessa área de segurança tudo e todos podem ser suspeito, o MITM pode ser realizado do lado do servidor e aí o end-to-end é inválido. Obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho você a dar uma pesquisada sobre acordo de chaves. 
O exemplo mais simples é o Diffie-hellman.

Não aconselho você criptografia de chave pública como RSA com cada usuário tendo uma chave pública e privada por que seria um overhead grande desnecessário. 
Nem usar RSA com o todo mundo encriptando com uma chave pública do servidor, já que nesse caso o servidor poderia abrir todas as mensagens dos usuários, o que do ponto de vista de segurança não muito legal.

Pro seu caso Diffie-helman da conta tranquilamente. Ainda mais sendo pra estudo, entender protocolos como Diffie-helman são essenciais em criptografia.

Comment: Oi, veja que eu acabei optando pelas duas opções, o usuario estabelece uma conexao segura (com o servidor) usando RSA para trocar parametros e depois ele recai sobre AES usando chave criada via DH. Para trocar dados entre usuarios eu optei por RSA com chave publica/privada por não ter muita escolha mesmo.

Comment: Ok. É melhor opção, eu preferiria usar ECC pra essas coisas. É mais leve e as chaves são beeem menores, mas se não há outra opção RSA serve.