# Transmitir informações sem passar pelo servidor

Tags: php, html5, servidor

A pergunta é simples e rápida, existe alguma forma de enviar dados sem a necessidade de que eles passem por um servidor, por exemplo enviar dados de um formulário que o usuário A preencheu para o usuário B em tempo real..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta simples e rápida seria **não**. Pelo menos não utilizando um browser, sem que ambos os usuários possuam um aplicativo específico para esse fim instalado em seus computadores.

Porém, como comentou abaixo o @GuilhermeBernal, existe o [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API), que ainda está em fase de especificação e não é suportado em todos os browsers. A API é toda voltada a comunicação em tempo real, porém, segundo [este tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-real) ainda é necessário utilizar servidores antes de estabelecer a conexão entre os navegadores, para que um saiba da existência do outro.

Comment: WebRTC não seria a solução para isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Pode ser mesmo. Apesar de que ainda está bem cru e com pouco suporte. Agora já não sei se edito ou excluo esta resposta...

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Por outro lado... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-real

Comment: Nunca usei na prática, não acho que consiga fazer um exemplo funcional. Provavelmente relevante: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14926093/517503 Mas infelizmente sim, precisa ter um servidor ao menos para iniciar a conexão. Mas dependendo do cenário (ao menos um par não estar atrás de um NAT) dá para fazer com que as mensagens em si não passem pelo servidor.