# Interpretaçao, MTProto encryption

Tags: criptografia, end-to-end

Alguém pode me ajudar a interpretar essa parte? de [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description)

> Antes de uma mensagem (ou uma mensagem concatenada) que estão sendo
>   transmitidos em uma rede usando um protocolo de transporte, que é
>   criptografada de uma certa maneira, e **um cabeçalho externo é
>   adicionado na parte superior da mensagem que é: um identificador de
>   chave de 64 bits ( que identifica de forma única uma chave de
>   autorização para o servidor, bem como o utilizador) e uma chave de
>   mensagem de 128 bits.**
>
> **Uma chave de usuário junto com a chave da mensagem definir uma real
>   chave de 256 bits e um vetor de inicialização de 256 bits, que é o que
>   criptografa a mensagem usando criptografia AES-256,** com extensão
>   garble infinito (IGE). Note-se que a parte inicial da mensagem seja
>   criptografado contém dados variáveis ​​(sessão, ID da mensagem, número
>   de seqüência, sal servidor) que **obviamente influencia a chave da
>   mensagem** (e, portanto, a chave AES e iv). **A chave da mensagem é
>   definido como os 128 bits de ordem inferior do SHA1 do corpo da
>   mensagem (incluindo sessão, mensagem de ID, etc.) mensagens de várias
>   partes são criptografadas como uma única mensagem.**

Estou tentando entender essas partes em negrito, para poder entender como eles conseguem variar as chaves de encriptação, segue as duvidas na ordem respectiva.

- Ok, imagino que esse cabeçalho nao seja criptografado (*), esse identificador é como se fosse uma chave única entre servidor e usuario para realizar a autenticaçao (*), o que é essa chave de mensagem?
- ele junta essas duas chaves? tipo A + B = AB? Essa chave de usuario é o identificador de chave?
- Sim, ele varia por causa dos "sessão, ID da mensagem, número de seqüência, sal servidor" (*)
- ESSA É A PARTE QUE REALMENTE NAO ENTENDO, alguém me explica? ordem inferiro do sha1 do corpo da mensagem? Oi?

(*) = Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** o texto a que você se refere é uma descrição do que o protocolo faz, sem indicar a motivação por trás do mesmo. Essa resposta segue na mesma linha.

Segundo este diagrama na [documentação oficial](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description):

[image: Diagrama do fluxo da criptografia]

Cada mensagem não usa a chave persistente diretamente, e sim uma nova chave derivada da mesma. Ambos os participantes possuem essa chave, mas há um outro parâmetro, variável, que é usado no processo de derivação, e que a outra parte (o destinatário) não tem acesso. Sendo assim, para que o destinatário seja capaz de decifrar a mensagem, é necessário passar para ele os parâmetros usados na encriptação, para que ele possa derivar a mesma chave e então usá-la. Isso é feito usando-se um cabeçalho externo, não criptografado:

> Antes de uma mensagem (ou uma mensagem concatenada) que estão sendo transmitidos em uma rede usando um protocolo de transporte, que é criptografada de uma certa maneira, e **um cabeçalho externo é adicionado** na parte superior da mensagem que é: **um identificador de chave** de 64 bits ( que identifica de forma única uma chave de autorização para o servidor, bem como o utilizador) e **uma chave de mensagem** de 128 bits.

Assim, o destinatário recebe a informação de *qual* chave secreta deve ser usada, e que parâmetro não secreto (a "chave de mensagem", que não deveria ser chamada de "chave", mas enfim...) deve ser usado junto a ela para derivar a chave verdadeira. Com isso ele pode refazer a chave usada para decifrar os dados encriptados.

> Uma chave de usuário junto com a chave da mensagem definem uma real chave de 256 bits e um vetor de inicialização de 256 bits, que é o que criptografa a mensagem usando criptografia AES-256, com extensão garble infinito (IGE).

O KDF ("função derivadora de chaves") usado então na chave secreta e "chave" de mensagem deriva a chave de descriptografia. Entretanto, em vez de se usar um IV ("vetor de inicialização") aleatório - o mais usual - ele usa o próprio KDF para derivar o IV também. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para opinar sobre isso, mas segundo [essa resposta](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38290/6939) a uma pergunta antiga minha no security.SE, a saída de um KDF é boa o suficiente para produzir duas chaves distintas - o que me leva a concluir que ela também é boa o suficiente para derivar um IV (já que este possui características de segurança mais "relaxadas" que as de uma chave - apenas tem de ser único, não secreto).

IGE é um [modo de operação](http://friedo.szm.com/krypto/JS/co0409.htm), usado para transformar um cifra de bloco (como o AES) numa cifra de fluxo. Cifras de bloco atuam em blocos simples de um tamanho fixo (128 bits no caso do AES), cifras de fluxo encriptam dados de tamanho arbitrário.

> Note-se que a parte inicial da mensagem seja criptografado contém dados variáveis ​​(sessão, ID da mensagem, número de seqüência, sal servidor) que obviamente influencia a chave da mensagem (e, portanto, a chave AES e iv).

Está simplesmente dizendo que se você mexer qualquer coisa na mensagem - inclusive nos seus metadados - a "chave" de mensagem vai mudar (já que ela é um hash de tudo isso). O que é bom, pois evita *replay attacks* (como [já explicado por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49933/215) na sua pergunta relacionada). Duas mensagens iguais, mas enviadas em momentos diferentes (e portanto com *timestamps* diferentes) serão encriptadas de modo diferente, não dando nenhuma informação útil ao atacante.

> A chave da mensagem é definido como os 128 bits de ordem inferior do SHA1 do corpo da mensagem (incluindo sessão, mensagem de ID, etc.) mensagens de várias partes são criptografadas como uma única mensagem.

Como já explicado, a mensagem e seus meta-dados são hasheadas para derivar a "chave" de mensagem. O hash [SHA-1](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1) possui uma saída de 160 bits, mas apenas os 128 bits "da direita" (os de ordem inferior/ordem mais baixa) são usados (ex.: "*2fd4e1c6* **7a2d28fc ed849ee1 bb76e739 1b93eb12**").

---

Respondendo às suas dúvidas específicas (que ainda não foram cobertas na explicação acima):

> ele junta essas duas chaves? tipo A + B = AB?

Sim ele junta, mas não através de uma operação aritmética simples, mas sim fornecendo ambas como entrada para um [KDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). Isso é para garantir o [efeito avalanche](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efeito_avalanche_%28criptografia%29) - a mudança de um única bit seja em uma chave ou na outra deve fazer com que todos os bits da saída tenham 50% de chance de mudar.

> Essa chave de usuario é o identificador de chave?

Se a criptografia é *end-to-end*, então assume-se que cada participante da comunicação possua um segredo compartilhado, desconhecido pelo(s) intermediário(s). Podem existir mais de um segredo. Então cada mensagem indica *qual* a chave que foi usada nessa mensagem, para que o destinatário possa decriptá-la.

Comment: Agora estou em dúvida se são os bytes da esquerda ou da direita na representação hexadecimal... *Endian* me confunde... :P

Comment: Oi, te respondo com mais perguntas haha (me desculpe), quando diz que cada mensagem não é encriptada com a chave persistente queres dizer que ele não usa a chave DH que ele criou na conversa diretamente. Certo? Poderia me dar um exemplo simples disso?

Comment: @user3715916 Vou chamar a chave DH de `dh`. Em vez dele estabelecer um `iv` separado e fazer `AES(dh,iv,mensagem)` ele faz `chave,iv = KDF(dh + msg_key)` e depois `AES(chave,iv,msg_key)`. Ou seja, ele não usa a chave DH *diretamente*, e sim **in**diretamente.

Comment: Mas se ele passa o parâmetro pro outro, essa proteção não pode ser considerada nula? Sendo que vai passar pela rede..

Comment: Mas um componente da geração de chave é secreto. Assumindo um KDF decente (leia sobre o Efeito Avalanche), só o conhecimento do componente não secreto (o `msg_key`) não ajuda em nada a descobrir o resultado final (a `chave` e o `iv`). Não sem a ajuda do componente secreto (o `dh`). Mesmo se essa "chave de mensagem" não fosse usada, ainda assim seria necessário passar um parâmetro adicional sem proteção, o IV. Por que eles não fazem simplesmente isso, eu não sei (reiterando, não tenho conhecimento para opinar sobre a motivação por trás do protocolo), mas do jeito que está não está ruim...

Comment: Viu porque sou fascinado nisso? Haha, andei a pesquisar sobre KDF e PHP, não obtive muito êxito mas isso é pra outra questão. A chave mensagem é um hash (feito com sha-1) do conteúdo a ser encriptada, correto ? Tipo, esse hash não pode ser quebrado? Por que como ele vai passar pela rede de ele for quebrado os muros de criptografia serão em vão. Se for o que eu penso, existe um algoritmo que eles mesmos publicaram mostrando como a chave key e iv é criada.

Comment: Se eu não me engano, eu li que depois da decriptar os dados faz um hash deles e depois ele faz uma comparação para evitar o CPA, é válida essa checagem não acha ?

Comment: @user3715916 O que você chama de "quebrado"? Inverter o hash (achar uma mensagem que, após hasheada, dá aquele hash) é impraticável - isso se chama resistência a pré-imagem, e é uma característica de todo hash bem feito. Por isso não é tão importante se esse hash é secreto ou não (e o sal no cabeçalho interno também ajuda). Quanto ao algoritmo que mostra como a chave e iv são criados, é esse mesmo mostrado no diagrama, não? (i.e. KDF na chave e na `msg_key`) O que é CPA? Chosen-Plaintext Attack? Não estou vendo relação alguma entre uma coisa e outra, mas também não conheço o protocolo a fundo.

Comment: Eu apenas comentei alguns pontos, por isso nao se ligaram muito. O que seria sal? Telegram menciona muito esse sal servidor.. Nunca acho o sentido. Veja em core.telegram.org/mtproto/description na parte "Defining AES Key and Initialization Vector" ele mostra um algoritmo para definiçao das chaves e sim CPA é "Chosen-Plaintext Attack" pelo que eu entendi esse ataque é a modificação da string encriptada afim de alterar a real funçao dela, e uma soluçao seria usar a msg_key (que é o hash da mensagem) para comparação no servidor depois, nao?

Comment: *"server salt"* se traduz para "sal **do** servidor", ou seja, um sal que vem do servidor. Sobre o que é o sal, acho que isso merece uma pergunta separada, não? Mas para uma referência rápida, [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/215) se menciona o sal e se explica brevemente sua utilidade. Não sei se [Chosen-Plaintext Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) é bem isso que você falou, mas de qualquer forma essa discussão em comentários já está por demais extensa... Por que não abre uma nova pergunta, como a que você fez para Chosen-Ciphertext Attack?

Comment: hahah concordo, Obrigado!