# Criptograr dados críticos no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, segurança, criptografia

Pensando em segurança, e em minimizar os problemas caso alguém desautorizado consiga ter acesso remoto ao servidor do banco de dados, pensei em criptografar os dados críticos.

Exemplos de dados críticos (definidos pelo cliente):

- Número de cartão de crédito: string;
- Código de segurança do cartão de crédito: inteiro;
- Salários: moeda;
- Razão social: string;
- CPNJ: string;
- Nome completo: string;
- CPF: string;
- Valores de receitas: moeda;
- Datas de recebimento: moeda;

Mas não seria viável caso perdesse funcionalidades nos campos criptografados como:

- order by CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO
- group by CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO
- where/having CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO like 'AB%'
- where/having CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO between 50 and 56
- where/having CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'
- where/having CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO > 23
- where/having CAMPO_CRIPTOGRAFADO < '2016-01-01'

Existe algum banco de dados relacional, de preferência *freeware*, que suporte a criptografia do campo sem perder os recursos acima?

Comment: desconheço isso, pensando teóricamente ele deve ser complexo de descriptografar, então acredito que se encontrar algo com essas propriedades ele vai ser tão burlável quanto não ter criptografia.

Comment: @pmargreff, todas as casas possuem chaves ou cadeados, e todas as chaves são burláveis, mas nem por isso você deixa de trancar sua casa não é verdade? Sei que não existe nada 100% seguro, mas tentarei dificultar o máximo.

Comment: 1) A real falha de segurança aqui está no acesso desautorizado ao seu servidor de banco de dados; 2) Da mesma forma que alguém desautorizado obteve uma senha/usuário de outra pessoa, também poderia obter a chave criptográfica; 3) A complexidade do que você sugere é gigantesca perto da facilidade de configurar corretamente as opções de segurança do seu servidor.

Comment: @AllanAndrade mas isso você não está considerando o esforço a mais de fazer a reordenação (que vocẽ mesmo sitou na pergunta), imagine ter que conferir os sofas das casas de acordo com o seu tamanho, é mais fácil e rápida manter todas as portas trancadas e ir abrindo uma de cada vez para a verificação ou manter um bom número de seguranças na rua e as casas abertas?

Comment: Isso que você quer já é possível *em teoria* - procure por ["Criptografia Homomórfica"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encripta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_homom%C3%B3rfica) para mais detalhes. No entanto, até onde eu saiba somente a IBM conseguiu realizá-la de fato, como prova de conceito, há poucos anos atrás. Ou seja, isso ainda está longe de estar disponível pro público em geral, não creio que exista qualquer banco de dados hoje que implemente a técnica, muito menos *freeware*.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @AllanAndrade A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, siga o que diz o Lacobus no comentário da pergunta.

Uma das coisas que deve fazer é criptografar o banco de dados como um todo. Não é uma solução 100% segura, mas é o mais simples de fazer e que provavelmente vai dar a melhor segurança que pode obter.

Feito isso o acesso será transparente. Mas se o servidor for comprometido a informação não estará segura. O único jeito de garantir que a informação jamais seja acessada indevidamente é garantindo que nem de forma devida seja possível :) E pior, o indevido pode um dia acontecer com muito esforço e descoberta que a técnica usada não era tão boa quanto se imaginava. A forma devida de acesso provavelmente não ocorrerá porque ninguém vai se esforçar para isso. Ou seja, é impossível fazer o que deseja.

Essencialmente todo banco de dados no mercado permite fazer a criptografia de um jeito ou de outro, até mesmo o SQLite que é muito simples consegue com um pequeno esforço adicional.

Se quiser criptografar apenas algo específico dá também.

A criptografia funciona na persistência (no armazenamento), um servidor comprometido pode ser acessado em outros pontos onde o dado não está criptografado, memória por exemplo.

Você poderia ter uma [criptografia *end-to-end*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49714/101), o que destruiria a função do banco de dados.

Comment: Interessante. Mas por que exatamente uma criptografia end-to-end destruiria a função do banco de dados ? Veja o Mega, por exemplo. Os arquivos ficam armazenados no servidor, mas apenas o usuário tem a chave.

Comment: Não sei o que eles fazem e se entregam o que prometem, mas se somente quem vai consumir o dado pode decifrá-lo, como uma *query* pode ser processada no banco de dados? Só teria informações criptografadas. Fica impossível manipular qualquer dado, vai ter que entregar tudo bruto e o cliente se virar para filtrar e fazer outras operações. Não faz sentido.

Comment: É verdade. Compreendo.

Comment: @bigown, obrigado pela atenção. Considerando que todos os esrforços para que ninguém indevido tenha acesso ao servidor estejam sendo providenciados. Mas também pensando na hipótese de que se mesmo assim, alguém conssiga ter o acesso. Como minimizar o comprometimento dos dados? Você sugeriu criptografar o banco de dados como um todo.... como fazer isso com MySQL? O que mais pode ser feito para evitar o comprometimento dos dados. Deste já muito obrigado pela atenção e "+1" pela resposta.

Comment: @AllanAndrade Cada banco de dados tem uma forma de fazer, alguns não possuem recursos tão à mão. Precisa perguntar especificamente para o MySQL. Não consigo imaginar nada a mais que possa ser feito. Com a criptografia os dados armazenados estão seguros, não sei se precisa fazer algo mais. O problema é o que vai pra memória. Não tem muito o que fazer aí, pelo menos não algo viável.

Comment: @bigown, alterei a pergunta para ficar específico para MySQL.

Comment: Como vcs já tão tratando do assunto entre vocês, não vou me meter, mas se não tivesse lido os comentários aqui eu teria revertido a edição, é o que eu faço quando o autor muda o essencial e já há respostas. Inclusive, o fato de ser MySQL não é relevante, o problema é mais fundamental, está no conceito das camadas e suas funções.

Comment: @Bacco boa, feito.