# Devo encriptar a password na aplicação ou no servidor?

Tags: android, segurança, servidor, criptografia

Eu estou a fazer uma aplicação que requer o registo dos utilizadores e a minha pergunta é se devo fazer a encriptação na aplicação e guardar no servidor ou enviar a *password* e fazer a encriptação no servidor na altura do registo?

Comment: Acho melhor na aplicação criar uma encriptação na aplicação depois no servidor decriptar e encriptar com outra criptografia, MD5 sei la. Porque pode ser que seja interceptada  antes de chegar no servidor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toda informação sigilosa deveria sempre ser trafegada de forma criptografada, desde onde ela foi digitada até o servidor. Pode utilizar os mecanismos disponíveis nos sistema operacional e acessíveis pela API do dispositivo.

No servidor quando receber deve imediatamente [transformar um *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101) e descartar a senha original.

Mais que isso só fazendo [criptografia *end-to-end*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49714/101), mas é um processo mais complicado, cria algumas dificuldades e só vale onde precisa de muita privacidade e precisa diminuir a área de ataque um pouco mais, o que nem garante nada porque a ponta pode estar comprometida de várias formas.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo de maneira clara e rápida: **o password deve ser encriptado na aplicação.**

## Por que?

Quando a aplicação envia os dados para o servidor, nada impede que esses dados não sejam lidos ou interceptados no meio do caminho, como por exemplo, um ataque  [Man in the middle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7051/conceito-de-ataque-man-in-the-middle). Quando esses dados transitam pela rede em *plain text* qualquer pessoa pode lê-la sem muitas dificuldades.

## Mas e se a comunicação for feita usando [https](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure)?

Com o uso do https entre serviços, é garantido a criptografia das mensagens trocadas entre os pontos, desde que os certificados e protocolos envolvidos estejam atualizados e operantes.

Por fim, o ideal seria a troca de mensagens usando criptografia end-to-end, como bem citou o @Maniero [em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231857/26520). Porém, devido ao alto custo e complexidade, se torna um pouco difícil de aplicar. Então, para o seu cenário, uma solução próxima do ideal seria: as informações partiriam do app já criptografadas diretamente para o seu servidor que usa o https.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta